# How to play html video using UI.Vision RPA extension

Tags: selenium, rpa

May I know how to execute to play video using the [UI Vision RPA](https://forum.ui.vision/) Extension. Despite using macro recording, I am unable to let the macro automatically play the YouTube video (for example)

I have the following JSON in the extension

```
{
  "Name": "Youtube",
  "CreationDate": "2020-4-15",
  "Commands": [
    {
      "Command": "open",
      "Target": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3L9_6aJi2Q&list=RDf3L9_6aJi2Q&start_radio=1",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "xpath=//*[@id=\"movie_player\"]/div[1]/video",
      "Value": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Spec:
**Firefox 75.0**
**Window 10**
**UI.Vision RPA 5.5.7**

Similar parallel thread about this problem also exist at this [forum](https://forum.ui.vision/t/how-to-play-html-video/5012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the YouTube video play automatically using the rpa extension, one need to used the [Xclick](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/xclick) with image recognition. The know-how is accessible from this [link](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/xclick)